# String passed to function, received as table

Tags: lua

In one file, I have the following code:

```
module( "command" )

local Commands = { }

function Add( cmd, funccallback )
  print(cmd)    
  Commands[ cmd ] = funccallback
end

Add("internal", function ( ) end )
```

in another I have the following:

```
command:Add("external", function( ) end )
```

this results in the following output:

```
>internal
>table: a008247
```

Why is the argument interpreted as an table in the second case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you called it with `:` instead of `.`. When you call something like this:

```
command:Add(...)
```

That is syntactical sugar for:

```
command.Add(command, ...);
```

You probably meant `command.Add`.

Comment: Substituting : for an . solved the problem. But I can't say I understand the sugar thing, though. Do you say that I could have written "external".Add(function ...) instead?

Comment: The `.` operator can only be used with tables or userdata. You can't use it on a string.

Comment: @NicolBolas, actually, you can, because Lua defines a metatable for strings. Try `print(("hello").len("1234"))`.

Comment: @lhf: True. But he couldn't call `Add` with it, unless he put it in the string metatable.

Comment: Ok. I can see that there is more to lua then I can learn in a couple of hours... ;-)